# How to choose from which side of QCPCurve fill with gradient?

Tags: c++, qt, graph, curve, qcustomplot

I am using qcustomplot and draw a curve (QCPCurve). Code below fills only area above the curve. But i want to fill area on other side of curve. And how to make gradient fill area till the borders of graph?

[image: what i need to do]

```
_myPlot->clearPlottables();

QVector<double> x;
QVector<double> y;

for(int point = 0; point < shadowZone.length() ; point++){
    x.push_back(shadowZone.at(point).longitude);
    y.push_back(shadowZone.at(point).latitude);
}

QBrush shadowBrush (QColor(0,0,0), Qt::Dense7Pattern);

QCPCurve *newCurve = new QCPCurve(_myPlot->xAxis, _myPlot->yAxis);
newCurve->setBrush(shadowBrush);
newCurve->addData(x,y);

_myPlot->replot();
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

One possible solution is to use `QCPGraph` instead of using `QCPCurve` to use `setChannelFillGraph()`, the strategy is to create another `QCPGraph` that is the lowest line of the graph, you must use the rangeChanged signals of the axes to update the graph if necessary.

```
QCPGraph *newCurve = new QCPGraph(_myPlot->xAxis , _myPlot->yAxis);
newCurve->addData(x,y);

QBrush shadowBrush(QColor(0,0,0), Qt::Dense7Pattern);

newCurve->setBrush(shadowBrush);

QCPGraph *minGraph = new QCPGraph(_myPlot->xAxis , _myPlot->yAxis);
newCurve->setChannelFillGraph(minGraph);

QObject::connect(_myPlot->xAxis, static_cast<void(QCPAxis::*)(const QCPRange &)>(&QCPAxis::rangeChanged), [_myPlot, minGraph](const QCPRange & newRange){
    minGraph->setData(QVector<double>{newRange.lower, newRange.upper},
                      QVector<double>{_myPlot->yAxis->range().lower,_myPlot->yAxis->range().lower});
});

QObject::connect(_myPlot->yAxis, static_cast<void(QCPAxis::*)(const QCPRange &)>(&QCPAxis::rangeChanged), [_myPlot, minGraph](const QCPRange & newRange){
    minGraph->setData(QVector<double>{_myPlot->xAxis->range().lower,_myPlot->xAxis->range().upper},
                      QVector<double>{newRange.lower, newRange.lower});
});
```

A complete example can be found in the following [link](https://github.com/eyllanesc/stackoverflow/tree/master/48365707)

[image]